# SQL Not Empty instead of Not NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, notnull

I am using postgreSQL. I have a column that:

```
NOT NULL
```

However when I want to insert a row with an empty string as like:

```
''
```

it doesn't give me an error and accepts. How can I check insert value should be `not empty`? (Neither empty nor null)

**PS:** My column defined as:

```
"ads" character varying(60) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add a constraint to column definition. For example something like:

```
ads character varying(60) NOT NULL CHECK (ads <> '')
```

For more, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: Why would you reference the old version 8.3? See here for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual

Comment: You can also add a domain if you use this more often: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html

Answer (score 11):

Found in the [current documentation of postgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) you can do the following to achieve what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
    did    integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('serial'),
    name   varchar(40) NOT NULL CHECK (name <> '')
);
```

From the documentation:

> **`CHECK ( expression )`**
>
> The CHECK clause specifies an expression producing a Boolean result
>    which new or updated rows must satisfy for an insert or update
>    operation to succeed. Expressions evaluating to TRUE or UNKNOWN
>    succeed. Should any row of an insert or update operation produce a
>    FALSE result an error exception is raised and the insert or update
>    does not alter the database. A check constraint specified as a column
>    constraint should reference that column's value only, while an
>    expression appearing in a table constraint may reference multiple
>    columns.
>
> Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row.

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.2? Version 8.2 was released in 2006 (!), it reaches [end of life this year](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Release_Support_Policy). Please reference `/current` if you don't need to address an old version. More info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual